# How to install Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M graphic card driver on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics

I know that there are some problems with the AMD graphics drivers in Ubuntu 16.04 but are there any solutions to solve this? I just found out about this after installing the new OS.

These are some info about my graphic cards and drivers:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
>
> /dev/video0
>   /dev/fb0
>   /dev/dri/card1
>   /dev/dri/renderD129
>   /dev/dri/controlD65
>   /dev/dri/card0
>   /dev/dri/renderD128
>   /dev/dri/controlD64
>
> server glx vendor string: SGI
>   client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
>       Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
>   OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
>
> *-display
>          description: VGA compatible controller
>          product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
>          vendor: Intel Corporation
>          physical id: 2
>          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>          version: 06
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>          configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>          resources: irq:33 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64)

Comment: In 16.04 you don't need to install any graphics drivers. Ubuntu should detect the card, and automatically use the radeon driver. It's not really a problem, since no one has to deal with fglrx stuff anymore.

Comment: Do you have some problems with graphics? Only open source drivers for AMD in 16.04 are the reason I'm waiting a little bit before installing 16.04. In 14.04 I had problems (crashes) with graphics drivers. It took me some time to figure out that open source drivers were the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes?_ga=1.53832616.166235725.1459944910#fglrx). It tells exactly what is going to happen, and IMHO, it is a step in the right direction, not a problem.

> The fglrx driver is now deprecated in 16.04, and we recommend its open source alternatives (radeon and amdgpu). AMD put a lot of work into the drivers, and we backported kernel code from Linux 4.5 to provide a better experience.
>
> When upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 from a previous release, both the fglrx driver and the xorg.conf will be removed, so that the system is set to use either the amdgpu driver or the radeon driver (depending on the available hardware).
>
> More information is available at https://tjaalton.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/no-catalystfglrx-video-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 1):

`fglrx` [is not available in 16.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04).  According to the linked article, "depending on your exact graphics hardware, Ubuntu 16.04 will use the open-source AMDGPU or the open-source Radeon driver in place of flgrx."